# MySQL - Getting results on a range by column value

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, limit, query-variables

### Solution B

As I accepted @Strawberry answer and this solution is out of the question of the post itself, I won't write it as an answer, but leave it here to anyone to whom it may be useful.

The main problem is a query performance and structure problem. The fact I am searching for all the attributes of all `slides` and after that limiting the results is making it go so slow. The solution would be to get first the slides I want to get and, then, searching all the extra information from that shorter set of results.

So, the final query (which runs under 0.2 seconds and gets all the results I wish) would be the following:

```
SELECT 
    sl.slide_id AS slide_id,        
    sl.time_in AS time_in,
    sl.time_out AS time_out, 
    sl.duration AS duration, 
    sl.slide_order AS slide_order,
    sl.title AS title,
    sl.slide_type AS slide_type, 
    sl.report_id AS report_id, 
    sltg.tag_category_id AS tag_category_id,
    sltg.tag_value_id AS tag_value_id,
    sltgc.txt AS tag_category_text,
    sltgv.txt AS tag_value_text,
FROM (SELECT 
        sl.time_in AS time_in,
        sl.time_out AS time_out, 
        sl.duration AS duration, 
        sl.slide_order AS slide_order,
        sl.media_id AS media_id,
        sl.title AS title,
        sl.slide_type AS slide_type, 
        slrep.report_id AS report_id, 
        slrep.slide_id AS slide_id
    FROM er_slides sl 
    INNER JOIN er_slides_in_report slrep 
        ON slrep.slide_id = sl.unique_id 
            AND slrep.report_id IN (1461317308472,1461597566425,1461598458236)  
            AND slrep.deleted_date IS NULL 
    LIMIT 0, 5
) sl  
INNER JOIN er_slides_tags sltg 
    ON sltg.deleted_date IS NULL 
        AND sltg.slide_id = sl.slide_id 
INNER JOIN er_slide_tags_categories sltgc
    ON sltgc.id = sltg.tag_category_id 
INNER JOIN er_slide_tags_values sltgv
    ON sltgv.id = sltg.tag_value_id 
ORDER BY slide_id, tag_value_id;
```

*As you can see, I limit the set before searching for anything else. After that, the query runs so fast. I hope that this approach helps someone to improve their own queries, taking my original one as an example of what you must NOT do.*

### The original question

I have a table with some elements (slides) which are grouped on some containers (reports), each one of those elements with some attributes (tag values) and categories (tag categories) assigned to them. It would be like a tagging system, where an element X can have the tag Y from the category Z.

### Database structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `er_reports` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unique_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(256) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `report_status` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'incomplete',
  `num_slides` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `report_type` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'report',
  `target_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `uploaded_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_reference` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_favourite` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_id` (`unique_id`),
  KEY `unique_id_2` (`unique_id`),
  KEY `unique_id_3` (`unique_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `deleted_date` (`deleted_date`),
  KEY `is_favourite` (`is_favourite`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=714 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `er_slides` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unique_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `report_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `action_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `thumbnail_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_offset` int(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `time_in` decimal(9,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_out` decimal(9,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` decimal(9,3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '10.000',
  `title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `slide_comment` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `note_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `media_object` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `slide_type` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'action',
  `user_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slide_order` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `count_slide` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `deleted_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `uploaded_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_reference` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `unique_id` (`unique_id`),
  KEY `report_id` (`report_id`),
  KEY `deleted_date` (`deleted_date`),
  KEY `action_id` (`action_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=31899 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `er_slides_in_report` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `report_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slide_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `slide_order` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `added_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `report_id` (`report_id`,`slide_id`,`deleted_date`),
  KEY `slide_order` (`slide_order`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=16843 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `er_slides_tags` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `slide_id` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tag_category_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `tag_value_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `deleted_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `slide_id` (`slide_id`,`tag_category_id`,`tag_value_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=220623 ;    

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `er_slide_tags_categories` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `txt` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `txt` (`txt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `er_slide_tags_values` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `txt` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `txt` (`txt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=439 ;
```

### What I've tried

```
SELECT @slide_num := if(@sl_id = slrep.slide_id collate utf8_unicode_ci, @slide_num, @slide_num := @slide_num+1) as slide_num,
    @sl_id := slrep.slide_id collate utf8_unicode_ci as sl_id,
    slrep.report_id AS report_id, 
    slrep.slide_id AS slide_id,
    sltg.tag_category_id AS tag_category_id,
    sltg.tag_value_id AS tag_value_id,
    sltgc.txt AS tag_category_text,
    sltgv.txt AS tag_value_text,
    sl.time_in AS time_in,
    sl.time_out AS time_out, 
    sl.duration AS duration, 
    sl.slide_order AS slide_order,
    sl.title AS title,
    sl.slide_type AS slide_type 
    FROM (SELECT @sl_id:=1, @slide_num := 0) v, er_slides sl
    INNER JOIN er_slides_in_report slrep 
        ON slrep.slide_id = sl.unique_id 
            AND slrep.report_id IN (1461317308472,1461597566425,1461598458236) 
            AND slrep.deleted_date IS NULL 
    INNER JOIN er_slides_tags sltg 
        ON sltg.deleted_date IS NULL 
            AND sltg.slide_id = sl.unique_id 
    INNER JOIN er_slide_tags_categories sltgc
        ON sltgc.id = sltg.tag_category_id 
    INNER JOIN er_slide_tags_values sltgv
        ON sltgv.id = sltg.tag_value_id 
    WHERE @slide_num >= 0 AND @slide_num <= 5
    ORDER BY slide_id, tag_value_id;
```

*I've put some fake report IDs for you to see how the query is constructed.*

### The problem

The problem is that this is not enough fast - it takes almost 3 seconds to get the information for 5 slides, 200 rows - and that I cannot modify the *from limit*. If I write:

`WHERE @slide_num >= 10 AND @slide_num <= 15`

I get an empty result (and, of course, I have checked there are enough slides).

I cannot understand neither why it takes 3 seconds to get 200 rows.

### What I need

I'd need to be able to query only those slides which are between the selected range, which is dynamic, in the fastest way possible.

If you find something is missing, comment what is it so I can post it.

Thank you.

### EDIT: Explain Query (Strawberry approach)

As @strawberry suggested, I tried to apply his approach. However, the response time of the query is the same writing a range from `BETWEEN 0 AND 5` than writing `BETWEEN 0 AND 200` (around 17 seconds both).

As this may be because of a bad indexing, I've decided to write the `EXPLAIN` here, as I cannot see any bad indexing (every condition put in a `WHERE` clause has its index).

[image: EXPLAIN result of @strawberry approach applied to my query]

Comment: Done - at least, I tried to. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's because I deleted some of the query extra information not needed for the question. It's solved now. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that as I have it needs to get the tags and not only the slides, one slide can have multiple tags, resulting in multiple rows per slide. So, `LIMIT 0, 5` would limit the number of rows, and that would mean getting maybe only 1 slide with 5 tags, when what I want is getting all tags for the first 5 slides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this simplified example...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS slides;

CREATE TABLE slides 
(slide_id INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO slides VALUES
(1),
(2),
(4),
(5),
(6),
(7);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS slides_tags;

CREATE TABLE slides_tags
(slide_id INT NOT NULL
,tag_id INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(slide_id,tag_id)
);

INSERT INTO slides_tags VALUES
(1,101),
(1,103),
(1,105),
(1,107),
(2,102),
(2,104),
(2,106),
(2,108),
(4,105),
(4,110),
(5,101);

SELECT slide_id
     , tag_id 
     , i
  FROM 
     ( SELECT s.*
            , st.tag_id
            , CASE WHEN @prev = s.slide_id THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
            , @prev:=s.slide_id 
         FROM slides s 
         LEFT 
         JOIN slides_tags st 
           ON st.slide_id = s.slide_id 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT @prev:=null,@i:=0) vars 
        ORDER 
           BY s.slide_id
     ) x 
 WHERE i BETWEEN 3 AND 5;
+----------+--------+------+
| slide_id | tag_id | i    |
+----------+--------+------+
|        4 |    105 |    3 |
|        4 |    110 |    3 |
|        5 |    101 |    4 |
|        6 |   NULL |    5 |
+----------+--------+------+
```

I've inlcuded the `i` column in the result for clarity. Of course, if it's not needed, omit it from the superquery.

EDIT:

It seems you *can* rewrite this query as follows but, to be honest, I'm baffled as to why this works:

```
SELECT s.slide_id 
     , st.tag_id
     , CASE WHEN @prev = s.slide_id THEN @i:=@i ELSE @i:=@i+1 END i
     , @prev:=s.slide_id 
  FROM (SELECT @i:=0, @prev := 0) vars
  JOIN slides s
  LEFT
  JOIN slides_tags st
    ON st.slide_id = s.slide_id
 HAVING i BETWEEN 3 AND 5
 ORDER 
    BY slide_id
     , tag_id;

+----------+--------+------+-------------------+
| slide_id | tag_id | i    | @prev:=s.slide_id |
+----------+--------+------+-------------------+
|        4 |    105 |    3 |                 4 |
|        4 |    110 |    3 |                 4 |
|        5 |    101 |    4 |                 5 |
|        6 |   NULL |    5 |                 6 |
+----------+--------+------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This is how I had it before. The problem - or at least, I think it is this way - is that being a subquery, it fetches the whole database, as there is no `WHERE` clause on the `x` table. Thus, it gives the correct result, but it takes as much as querying the whole database without `WHERE` (on my tests, doing so would last 70 seconds or more, returning only a small set of slides).

Comment: That doesn't sound right. On an appropriately indexed table, this query should be blisteringly fast.

Comment: Then, there's something I cannot understand. When doing the query as I posted on the question, I get the right results with a time of 3 seconds. If I make the same query as you suggested (with the same `BETWEEN`), then I get the same results with 17 seconds. If I change the `BETWEEN` values to a shorter - or larger - one, I get no difference on the time of response. I think it's well indexed, but anyway the fact I get the same time no matter what range I write indicates it's doing the same work every time: fetching the whole database. Isn't it? How can I see it?

Comment: Yes, I get the right results, just I cannot edit the `BETWEEN` range. I get an empty result. And, though 3 seconds may seem a good time, I find that for a 5 slide response is just too high, that's why I asked too `the fastest way possible`.

Comment: And sorry, maybe I didn't explain well. I applied your approach of making a subquery `SELECT * FROM (SELECT ....) x WHERE i BETWEEN 3 AND 5;` to my query. As I commented before, I'm getting the right results, but I am getting the same 17 seconds timing using both `BETWEEN 3 AND 5` and `BETWEEN 0 AND 200`, so it's not filtering the results on the subquery which is the same as querying the whole database each time. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: I accept this answer as the correct one because you wrote the right way the thing I was doing wrong in my original post: the correct form is `HAVING slide_num BETWEEN x AND y ORDER BY...` and not as I posted originally. Thank you for your time and help!